# Views are not aligned in an horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In a ListView getview() method, I build my layout like this :

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200));
layout.setWeightSum(120);
for (int i = 0; i < totalTVNumber; i++) {
    LifeEvent event = getEventFromDB(cost, position);
    if (event != null) {
        TextView eventTV [![enter image description here][1]][1]= event.getTextView(getContext());
        eventTV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 200, getTheWeight(eventTV)));
        layout.addView(eventTV);
    }
}
```

The problem is that doing this will cause my view not to be exactly aligned vertically. Since they have the same height than the layout, I expected them to match it but **some views (nearly 1 on 2) act like they have a little margin-top**. Of course there is nothing like a margin-top in my code, and reading their margin onClick returns 0.

Adding `layout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);` doesnt change anything, and adding  `eventTV.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);` just put the text on the top of the TV.

Note that if I go for `MATCH_PARENT` intead of 200 for the event, it acts exactly as expected, but I would like the views to be a little smaller than the layout, to get a little gap between them.

In case it matters, a LinearLayout can have from 2 to 9 textviews inside, and their weight are calculated to sum to 120 (for instance 44+34+2+40). Horizontal behaviour is ok.

**How can I align view on the top of my horizontal linearlayout ?**

EDIT : here is a screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Add a snapshot of the output you are getting and sample of your desired output.

Comment: Have you tried setting your LinearLayout's orientation, layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL); ?

Comment: default orientation is Horizontal, but no, it doesn't change anything